# How to share onBackPressed with multiple custom classes (like ViewPager) if its not initialized inside Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have abstract class (Activity) with `onBackPressed` function. What I want to achieve is to share and implement this `onBackPressed` in any custom UI component, like my custom `ViewPager` which is managing flow (If I use system back button, it will switch page to previous instead of generic back button function in Activity). I wanna make something like custom listener, which will listen to back button action which I can implement like `Interface` or some sort of `open class` to any custom class I make, not just extended `Activity` class.

Answer (score 0):

you should override  `onBackPressed()` function on your activity . Then get the position of viewpager list item

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

       //do here like 
       if(viewpager_positon == 1){
                        }...
                           
          
    }
```

Comment: Thats the problem. My ViewPager is not inside Activity. Activity is managing multiple things, and my ViewPager is just abstract class which is extending other class. ViewPager doesnt have direct access to activity at all.

Comment: then you can use listener.